# YII: Show a different image if no image available?

Tags: php, yii

I am pulling posts from a database and want to display a default image if no image are available for a certain post. This is my current code:

```
<img alt="" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/uploads/classifieds/<?php echo ClassifiedImages::getTitleImage ($data->id)->filename; ?>" width="112" height="83" />
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you, instead of

```
<?php echo ClassifiedImages::getTitleImage ($data->id)->filename; ?>
```

write

```
<?php echo (ClassifiedImages::getTitleImage ($data->id)->filename=="") ? 
"no-picture.jpg" : ClassifiedImages::getTitleImage ($data->id)->filename; ?>
```

If the filename is empty, it will be replaced with "no-picture.jpg".

You can also use jQuery if you know that.

```
$("#yourdivid img").error(function(){
     $(this).html("src","<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>/no-picture.jpg");
});
```

Comment: this should do the trick, +1

Comment: What you might want to do is create a param in your main/config.php file, and call that each time you display the default image. That way it's a bit more dry, and if you want to change the default image sometime in the future, you only need to change it in once place.